# Benefit of a multi-column unique constraint on a small table

Tags: sql, database-administration

I have a SQL table that generally contains less than 100 rows and contains a primary key.  It also contains a unique constraint on a group of 3 columns, but in some cases that constraint is not valid so I am coding around it.  I would like to remove the constraint but do not know if this will have negative implications.  From my research there may be a performance hit, but the table contains so few rows and rows are never searched on using these 3 columns.  What are the reasons for having this type of constraint?

Comment: A contraint ensures data integrity. Now, if you say that sometimes the contraint is not valid, that means there are cases where duplicate values are expected. In short, do you need to ensure uniqueness or not? If the answer is "no", then remove the constraint.

Comment: you could always an an index for all three columns with using unique